# Is NetworkManager itself capable of creating a new Wifi connection?

Tags: linux, networkmanager

Manual pages of NetworkManager mentions that it "manages Wifi network interfaces", however it does not say whether it can create new Wifi connections.

NetworkManager applet appears to be able to create new Wifi connections, however NetworkManager CLI manual does not mention anything about Wifi. Thus adding more to my confusion.

So after all, what functions does NetworkManager provide in "managing Wifi network interfaces"? Does NetworkManager rely on other programs to create new Wifi connections?

Answer (score 1):

NetworkManager does have a `/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings` object with a `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings` interface with a `AddConnection()` method, but documentation for the argument is [a bit lacking](https://live.gnome.org/NetworkManagerDBusInterface/LatestDBusAPI#org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings.AddConnection).

TL;DR: Yes, mostly. But it has to be instructed to create the connection by a separate program.